# Page formating issue while load for the first time but formating issues gone while clicking on the refresh button in IE8 browser, why?

Tags: asp.net

In IE8 for the very first time the page loads; have lost its format (i.e. may be not able to properly loading the css class) however on clicking the refresh button of that page the issue gone.
Can anyone suggest why this is happening and how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have a link I could look at?  Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: No I haven't find any error on the page, even no javascript error.

Comment: it's hard without anything to look at - if this happens every time then download fiddler and check to see if everything is loading correctly.  Just one thing, if you open the page do ctrl & f5, close IE down and load up - does the error still happen?

Comment: it is not happning with all the IE 8 browsers however one of the user is getting this formating issue, I have checked the browser settings and found that only the Java version is different. However when she clicks on the refresh button the issue gone. I am wondering whether this problem is due to some settings or releted with the IE 8 version? If you need any information which will help you understand the problem properly then please let me know, i will try to provide you the same. Many thanks for your responce....

Answer (score 0):

Without more information or a url I'm guessing that this is a caching issue.

Try adding the following to your page - this will let the browser know to not cache so aggressively.

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" >
```

Or if its just the style-sheet that's affected you could try versioning it.

If any of this doesnt help, you could download fiddler [from here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - install it and you can see exactly what's happening on your page requests.

Comment: Does the user get the problem consistently for example if they refresh the browser (which fixes it) then close and open the browser do they still have the formating issue. Do you have access to the users machine?

Comment: Yes the user still have the formating issue but not consistently (actually the formating issue is not consistent throughout the application, it might be possible that first time the user is getting the issue in a page and after closing the browser when reopened it the user might get problem in another page or in same page). I don't have access to the users machine but according to her sometime she is getting formating issue on pages and sometime she is not getting formating issue; however when she get the issue in a page on click of the refresh button solves the formating issue.

Comment: mmm without a link and taking a look I can't think of much to suggest. I have seen it where style sheets havent been loaded due to network timeouts. If possible I would give her instruction to install fiddler. Set it running and capture the pages request/responses then ask her to email the results back to you. You can then see if any of the requests are timing out.